# Getting error while setting Slug in laravel --- profile%20/%20

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**My li link to  profile**

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/profile/') }} / {{ Auth::user()->slug }}">Profile</a></li>
```

My route file

```
Route::get('/profile/{slug}','ProfileController@index');
```

**My profilecontroller page**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index($slug){
        return view('profile.index');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a name for every route like:

```
Route::get('/profile/{slug}','ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
```

Then you can call this like:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('profile', Auth::user()->slug) }}">Profile</a>
</li>
```

---

If you don't want to use route name. You can do this like:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ url('/profile/').Auth::user()->slug }}">Profile</a>
</li>
```

Comment: it works too but i remove sapces in my <LI> and then it works. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: @rahul Using route name is good practice. So I recommend you to declare a unique name for every route. Anyway welcome. :)

Comment: but i set  it in route file also ..so how it effect?

Answer (score 2):

Remove Space

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/profile/') }}/{{ Auth::user()->slug }}">Profile</a></li>
```

Comment: @rahul: Glad to help and if my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your model and add this function

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

This will instruct laravel to use "slug" as the router key, instead of ID

Comment: In my User model?